# How do I read a file based on a parameterised filename, given a URI of a user selected directory?

Tags: java, android, storage-access-framework

I am trying to build an Android app that allows a user to select a folder containing images, and from that point onwards, the app is able to load specific images by pre-determined image names placed in that user selected folder. The use case is enabling the app user to customise themes/images of the app by providing their own assets.

I can get the URI of the user selected folder ok. Assuming that the required image files with the required filenames will always be present in the user selected folder (I have implemented try-catch blocks to deal with this), how do I construct a Uri for the image file so I can use it (e.g. to set an ImageView?)

The user must be able to select from a range of locations for assets, including an SD card.

```
//Key variables
ImageView myImageView;
String myImageFilename = "foobar.png"; //image to be loaded
Uri imageUri;
Integer MYREQUESTID = 100000000;

//This is how the user selects a directory:
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE);
startActivityForResult(intent, MYREQUESTID);

//Use on activity result to capture the user selected folder;
URI userSelectedDirUri = data.getData();
```

Tried the following to append the filename onto the user selected directory, but it results in an invalid Uri. I notice that the Uri is encoded with %2F instead of /, but using this method the filename is appended with / and I can't work out how to use %2F instead

```
imageUri = userSelectedDirUri.buildUpon().appendPath(myImageFilename).build();
```

The following works, but the pickedDir.findFile(...) results in 50,000+ calls to the listFile() and findFile() method that is causing constant garbage collection. The user's folder may contain 100+ files.

```
DocumentFile pickedDir = DocumentFile.fromTreeUri(context, directoryUri);
DocumentFile theFile = pickedDir.findFile(myImageFilename);
imageUri = theFile.getUri();
```

The goal

```
myImageView.setContentUri(imageUri);
```

This last line of the code should update the ImageView myImageView with the image called myImageFilename, residing in the directory described by userSelectedDirUri.

Any help appreciated! I am also not implementing this as an asyncTask which I think I should be. Extra kudos/points/gratitude for examples using and not using asyncTask, but not essential (will work it out myself once the core logic is fixed).

Thanks!

Comment: "Tried the following to append the filename" -- the user can choose a document tree from any eligible provider. There is no requirement for the filename to be part of the `Uri` for all providers. There is no requirement for filenames to *exist* for all providers.

Comment: "The following works, but the pickedDir.findFile(...) results in 50,000+ calls to the listFile()" -- it looks like a single call to `findFile()` results in a single call to `listFiles()`, based on [this implementation](https://github.com/aosp-mirror/platform_frameworks_support/blob/androidx-1.0-dev/documentfile/src/main/java/androidx/documentfile/provider/DocumentFile.java#L336-L344). It will result in N additional queries, though, to get the display name for comparison (where N is the number of items in the list).

Comment: You should be able to create a more efficient `findFile()` implementation that retrieves the display names for each child in the initial `query()`, so you can just iterate over the `Cursor` to hunt for a match. See [the existing `listFiles()` implementation](https://github.com/aosp-mirror/platform_frameworks_support/blob/androidx-1.0-dev/documentfile/src/main/java/androidx/documentfile/provider/TreeDocumentFile.java#L134-L163) for a starting point.

Comment: Thanks for the insight @CommonsWare. Considering I have to load many assets like this, would it be a good idea to index all of the images once into some kind of map? The idea is even if I write a more efficient findFile(), it will still be O(N) every time I need to load a file. Indexing it into a map first will help make it O(1) after initial indexing. If there's a problem getting a particular image, I can handle that exception with an option to "rediscover assets" (re-index).

Comment: Yes, I would query `DocumentsContract` once and use that result for processing all of your files, at least for each "transaction" (iteration through your file list). Given your use case, I assume that you are loading all of the details for your theme in one shot. So, basically, query `DocumentsContract` once to load the theme details, then again if the user switches themes, requests a refresh, etc. You could try to set up a `ContentObserver` for the `Uri` representing the document tree, to detect changes in real time, though I don't know if that works with all document providers.

Comment: Tried:
`ContentResolver contentResolver = this.getContentResolver();
Uri childrenUri = DocumentsContract.buildChildDocumentsUriUsingTree(userSelectedDirUri,                     DocumentsContract.getTreeDocumentId(userSelectedDirUri));
Cursor childCursor = contentResolver.query(childrenUri, new String[]{ DocumentsContract.Document.COLUMN_DOCUMENT_ID}, null, null, null);`

But the following has permission denial and I'm pretty stuck: `imageView.setImageURI(DocumentsContract.buildDocumentUri(userSelectedDirUri.getAuthority(),childCursor.getString(0)))` Am I missing something, @CommonsWare?

Comment: At this point, you are better served asking a fresh Stack Overflow question, where you provide your current code (with relevant snippets from this question, including how you got `userSelectedDirUri`), along with the stack trace. I have not worked directly with `DocumentsContract` to this extent. Also, check your original `DocumentFile` code, perhaps using a smaller directory, and confirm whether you have rights to a child image. If you do, then your code in your comment must be different than what `DocumentFile` uses, and you can try to determine the differences.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved using the approach suggested by @CommonsWare.

```
Hashmap<String, Uri> imageUriMap = new Hashmap<>; //Defined outside of this method

public String indexImages(Uri userSelectedDirUri){

    ContentResolver contentResolver = this.getContentResolver(); //When this method is used in the context of an Activity.
    Uri childrenUri = DocumentsContract.buildChildDocumentsUriUsingTree(uri,
            DocumentsContract.getTreeDocumentId(uri));

    Cursor c = null;

    c = contentResolver.query(childrenUri, new String[] {
            DocumentsContract.Document.COLUMN_DISPLAY_NAME,
            DocumentsContract.Document.COLUMN_DOCUMENT_ID}, null, null, null);

    Integer count = 0;
    try {
        while (c.moveToNext()) {
            final String documentName = c.getString(0);
            final String documentId = c.getString(1);
            final Uri documentUri = DocumentsContract.buildDocumentUriUsingTree(uri,
                    documentId);
            imageUriMap.put(documentName, documentUri);
            count++;
        }
    } finally {
        c.close();

    }
    return (count.toString() + " images indexed");
}
```

Then set images using:

```
imageView.setImageUri(imageUriMap.get(myImageFilename));
```